# Cisco: 9606R Switch Firmware update

Tags: cisco, cisco-catalyst, network-core, firmware, os-upgrade-procedure

I have updated my other Cisco 9300 switches, but am a bit confused on how to even select the right firmware for my Cisco 9606R Core.

If I run *sh ver* it displays the following:

```
Cisco IOS XE Software, Version 17.09.01
Cisco IOS Software [Cupertino], Catalyst L3 Switch Software (CAT9K_IOSXE), Version 17.9.1, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc8)
```

Running the *sh platform* shows that all the slots are in 17.8.1r[FC1].

At the Cisco Software [Download page](https://software.cisco.com/download/home/286322137) I am not sure which to select nor how to properly apply the update.

Comment: I'm left with more questions than answers. Cisco doesn't list 17.9 for the 9606R, but 17.9 is "universal" for 9[3456]00. 17.9 does exist for the SUP (1 and 2.) What's you reason for any upgrade? Have you looked through the voluminous platform and release notes?

Comment: 17.8.1r[FC1] is a SUP 1 ROMMON version number.

Comment: I have some outstanding CVEd that need to be patched. Would you recommend I leave it alone and only update the access and distribution switches? They all are all on 17.9.4a